# Bounds on $\sum_{l=0}^j (-1)^l 3^{j-l}\binom{j}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha n} \binom{n-j}{k-l}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, upper-lower-bounds

In the course of solving some optimization, I encountered the following sum:

$\sum_{l=0}^j (-1)^l 3^{j-l}\binom{j}{l}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-j}{k-l}=2^n, \quad j\in\left\{0,1,\dots,n\right\}$.

I am interested in obtaining closed-form lower and upper bounds on the partial sum of this kind, i.e.

$\sum_{l=0}^j (-1)^l 3^{j-l}\binom{j}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\alpha n} \binom{n-j}{k-l}, \quad j\in\left\{0,1,\dots,n\right\}$.

A result for $0.5 < \alpha < 1$ fixed would still be useful.

I have been trying to deal with it for a longer period of time, look for some combinatoric identities etc. but the alternating terms and the partial sum of a binomial coefficient make it really complicated. I do not specialize in this kind of stuff, though, so I decided to look for help here.

Any hints are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is always maximized around $\binom{n}{n/2}$ for $n$ even, and a similar expression for $n$ odd. You could use that for an upper bound, though it probably wouldn't be very good. The lower bound for a binomial coefficient is always $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, using this kind of bound solely on the binomial coefficient here gets tricky because it is an alternating sum...

Comment: Well, that depends on whether you want a lower bound the magnitude, or on the actual value. If you want a lower bound on the actual value, set $(-1)^l=-1.$ For an upper bound, just set $(-1)^l=1.$

Comment: I would agree that a lower bound on the magnitude would be tricky.